Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.TypedResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration app:debugRuntimeClasspath
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.TypedResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
Received this error
my build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '8.5.1'
        agp_version1 = '8.5.0'
        agp_version2 = '8.0.0'
        agp_version3 = '8.5.1'
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/" }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}


//        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/" }


//        maven { url 'repo.grails.org/grails/core' }
        jcenter()

        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$agp_version3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.8, 0.99.99]'

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
//        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


my build.gradle app side+6
//apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shoaib.keto"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 54
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.6.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        }
//        lintOptions {
//            checkReleaseBuilds false
//            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
//            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
//            abortOnError false
//        }
    }
   

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.4.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-text:1.0.0-beta04'
    implementation project(path: ':storage')
    implementation project(path: ':storage')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:34.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:6.2'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
    implementation 'com.devlomi.record-view:record-view:2.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:1.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:1.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
//    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.15.0, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.github.rkmobile2519:customedittext:1.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.jaiselrahman:FilePicker:1.3.2'
//    implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.4'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1"
//    implementation project(path: ':fileImagepicker')
    implementation 'com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.vincent.filepicker:MultiTypeFilePicker:1.0.8'
//    implementation 'me.rosuh:AndroidFilePicker:0.5.3'
    implementation project(path: ':filepicker')

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
//    implementation 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
//    implementation 'com.aghajari.emojiview:AXEmojiView:1.2.4'
//    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-ios:0.7.0'
    implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-google:0.8.0'

//    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android")
//    implementation 'com.filestack:filestack-android:5.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Adilhusen:circle-progress-ad-android-:1.0'
//    implementation project(":pdfViewer")
//    implementation project(":videpplayer")
//    implementation project(":pix")
//    implementation project(":customcamera")
//locale changer
    implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:LocaleChanger:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:13.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:13.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
//    implementation 'com.camerakit:camerakit:1.0.0-beta3.11'
//    implementation 'com.camerakit:jpegkit:0.1.0'

    implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.OverflowArchives:AndroidLinkPreviewer:0.01'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.3.0'
    // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
    // So, make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
    implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0")

    // For Kotlin users also import the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
    implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0")
    implementation 'com.github.MohammedAlaaMorsi:RangeSeekBar:1.0.6'
//    implementation  'io.ak1.pix:piximagepicker:1.6.3'
    implementation 'com.github.CameraKit:camerakit-android:v1.0.0-beta3.11'
    implementation 'com.github.CameraKit:jpegkit-android:v0.2.2'

}


changed gradle  jdk version
too
Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because the Gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME locations are different. Project 'CobroKing-Native-3.0' is using the following JDK location when running Gradle: 'C:/Users/shoaib/.jdks/openjdk-23.0.1' The system environment variable JAVA_HOME is: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6' If you dont need to use different paths (or if JAVA_HOME is undefined), you can avoid spawning multiple daemons by setting JAVA_HOME and the JDK location to the same path.
i have tried offline mode from gradle it did not work
i hace tried to update gradle jdk 23.0.1
